# Android 2.3.4 TelephonyManager

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I updated my HTC Flyer to Android 2.3.4. Now I am not able to retrieve the IMEI number through `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`. It always return **null**.

Can somebody try to read out the IMEI on another device. I would like to know whether it is a Google or HTC problem.

Sorry for the bad english.

Comment: have you got IMEI with `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()` before update?

Comment: problem can be with permissions, to read IMEI code of phone you must write in your **AndroidManifest.xml** this: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

Comment: Yeah me too facing this same issue.... Did u got solution Roberto Schumann??

Answer (score 1):

I have five HTC flyer, three of them have been updated. Unfortunately, only the updated flyers can't get the IMEI code via the function TelephonyManager.getDeviceId(). My programs on sumsung galaxy, viewpad, and these un-updated flyers work well.